# "Cite" link in Chem.SE?

Tags: feature-request

"Cite" link was neatly added to Physics.SE (see relevant posts in their meta: [1](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7056/what-is-the-function-of-cite-below-each-question-answer), [2](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5495/a-cite-this-paper-will-you-button), [3](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4189/how-can-i-cite-a-question-in-se); [4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189213/add-the-ability-to-cite-questions-and-answers)).

Shouldn't we have it too?

Comment: I see no reason to object.

Answer (score 7):

The feature itself isn't new—it's just [more obvious now](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/2436/36770). I'm happy to add it for Chemistry if it's likely to be used. The one caveat I have is that [chemistry.stackexchange.com is not often cited](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=chemistry.stackexchange.com) in academic papers (cf. [MathOverflow](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=mathoverflow&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5)). Obviously, there could be a chicken and egg problem here: we don't have a citation link, so nobody cites the site.

A significant cost of adding the feature is a new menu item under every post. That's hardly a problem if y'all use the link. But it's a waste of cognitive space if the feature isn't used much. So if the community would like to have citations, I'd appreciate someone helping me find examples of Chemistry—Stack Exchange being used as a reference in academic settings. That way, I can be confident that turning on the citation feature will meet an actual need.

Comment: I think it would be a lot more likely to be used if it is seen than if not. Some posts here nicely explain mechanisms, sometimes even backed with further citations from literature. Also, some people have disclosed that they did calculations specifically for the site that they wouldn’t publish elsewhere. I don’t think it would hurt *at all* to have it included, but it might hurt to not include it. That is without me actually being able to point to a citation of whatever.stackexchange.com in literature.

Comment: @JonEricson I'd also like to have a "cite" feature for teaching hand-outs and slides. That way my students can follow-up on Chem.SE "in the open." I'd say it's not just for academic papers.