# Addition of the cite link revisited

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

Triggered by a question on academia.se about a possibly AI generated publication under review ([link](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/199417/reviewing-a-paper-which-i-suspect-has-been-generated-by-ai#199417)), and drawing inspiration from mattermodelling.se, I became curious if their `cite` button would be a feature generally perceived as useful here on chemistry.se.  The button in question appears below questions and answers, provides a brief snippet of  BibTeX including the post's title, author, web site address, date of the most recent edit which enters nicely into the database of a reference manager like [zotero](https://www.zotero.org/), for example.

As an illustrative example from mattermodelling.se (link to the [post](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/questions/11336/what-factors-could-cause-a-calculation-to-run-successfully-on-a-laptop-but-encou)):

[image]

Comment: Related, old duplicate: https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2924/4945

Comment: Possibly implemented earlier than today, 2023-08-07 Mon, but questions on chemistry.se now carry a a cite button/option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Update:

Through "secret" channels we achieved implementation of this feature.

Even though I did not ask very nicely, the higher ups followed my request. Thanks again for that.

---

Original:

This was brought up quite a while ago and I don't remember why we didn't follow up with the suggestion. I've linked the question and closed the old one as a duplicate.

I personally agreed with the proposal back then and I still agree with it today.

Since the way to move forward with feature requests has changed significantly over the last years, I (or the moderators) will have to check back how to escalate things. I'm pretty sure a few upvotes will help with signaling agreement.

Comment: Well, would you look at that… https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/51/49

Comment: For me it would be just more fluff (like why is some "follow" between edit and close/flag?), but if people would actually use it...